Terminal doesn't open in Ubuntu 22.04
The problem is the same as in this video, but the solution does not help
Trying to open via terminal with the gnome-terminal command, I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)

I tried to reinstall the terminal using the commands sudo apt remove --purge gnome-terminal and sudo apt install gnome-terminal, but it did not help

The video doesn't show VSCode at all, what are you doing exactly, are you running gnome-terminal inside VSCode's terminal? In any case, which version of gnome-terminal (gnome-terminal --version)? Please add this information to the question, thanks

vscode is not important here, I just use the terminal built into it, it's the same bash.
When I try to execute gnome-terminal --version I get the same error

It is important, the environment in which bash runs is normally very different in VSCode. So knowing that could help. Then please run dpkg -s gnome-terminal | grep '^Version', it should show the installed package's version.

I run gnome-terminal in vscode terminal, and I also installed some xterm, and I get the same error there.
Version: Version: 3.44.0-1ubuntu1

Ok, what happens if you run sudo apt install --reinstall python3-gi?

Also I'd make sure everything is up to date. sudo apt update && sudo apt-upgrade

If VScode isn't relevant, and you get the same error when trying to launch gnome-terminal from within xterm, then please edit this information into the question and, ideally, remove mention of VScode since it is misleading. If, however, you only get this error when trying to launch a terminal tool from within the VScode terminal, then please edit and clarify that.

I ran this command  sudo apt install --reinstall python3-gi and reinstalled, but the error remained.
I also did sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade more than once, it doesn’t help
